# how to get the inputStream from Workbook object in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I upload the file i am passing the inputstream to the workbook. Now I want to use this `InputStream` from workbook in another method like save where I save the file `InputStream` in to DB. Here is my code.

```
public void FileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws ParseException  {
    UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
    Workbook workbook = org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(item.getInputStream());
}
```

Now I want to make Workbook object as instance variable and pass to another method like below.

```
public String save() throws SQLException, IOException{
    fileId = dao.savefile(workbook,fileName);
}
```

In my savefile method

```
InputStream inptest=  **workbook.getStream**
    ps.setBinaryStream(2,fin,fin.available());
```

So `inptest` variable accepts `InputStream` which I wanted to get it from Workbook.

Comment: What library and package is a `Workbook`?

Comment: i use poi-ooxml-3.9.jar .

Comment: what is the question exactly?

Comment: How to read the inputstream from workbook .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like what you are asking for is a way to use the InputStream for multiple purposes:

1. To create a Workbook object (which you're already doing)
2. To save the content of that InputStream somewhere else

Since reading from an InputStream is usually a one-time-only operation that cannot be repeated, then you can do the following:

1. Save the full content of the InputStream to a buffer.
2. Open two new InputStreams from the buffer.
3. Pass your InputStreams to your two methods.

Code might look like this:

```
public void FileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws ParseException  {
    UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();
    InputStream originalInputStream = item.getInputStream();

    byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(originalInputStream);
    InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
    InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);

    Workbook workbook = org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(is1);
}

InputStream inptest = is2;
ps.setBinaryStream(2,fin,fin.available());
```

Note: this uses [Apache Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) for IOUtils.

Comment: Glad it worked! If a solution worked for you, common etiquette here is to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check-mark. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to save the Workbook object to a file, there is a method [write()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write(java.io.OutputStream)) which takes in an OutputStream. Saving to a file can then be accomplished by

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path/to/file/[filename]");
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

Comment: It should work, but it depends on what you are trying to do. You may also need to close the FileOutputStream to get the file to appear. Edited above.

Comment: I think you are not clear about my question. I want to read inputstream from workbook so lets say as per your code i write to workbook then how do i get the inputstream from that. Please let me know if there is any such method.

Comment: Do you mean retrieve the original InputStream from the Workbook object? As far as I know there's no way to do so. If you want to retain it across to the savefile method you should add it as an instance var also.

Comment: yes retrieve the original InputStream from the Workbook object. Anyways thanks for your time.